# How does wordpress password hash work?

Tags: php, python, django, wordpress

I need to integrate a Django system with a Wordpress site, as in wordpress users should be able to log in the DJnago part and vice versa,

For this I need to understand how the password hashing works in Wordpress. I can see the `wp_users` table which stores the username and password hashes.

Looking through the wordpress code, I can see the password is set via [wp_set_password](http://lab.yukei.net/wp-code/nav.html?_functions/index.html), which is using [hash_password](http://lab.yukei.net/wp-code/nav.html?wp-includes/class-phpass.php.html#hashpassword) to hash the password.

Now I dont know enough PHP to understand how it is working. I need to replicate the same in python so I can validate the password from Django part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a comment in the implementation saying:

```
  28  /**
  29   * Portable PHP password hashing framework.
  30   *
  31   * @package phpass
  32   * @version 0.1 / genuine
  33   * @link http://www.openwall.com/phpass/
  34   * @since 2.5
  35   */
```

The hashing framework used is [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), and its page links to a Python implementation. [Here's the link (.tar.gz)](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/contrib/phpass-python-0.1.tar.gz). That page has some other useful links (such as a Perl implementation).

Comment: The checkpassword is using `$settings`, (I assume to get the setting to salt with?) Don't I need that for validating the password?

Comment: You'll need the same input (like salt) to the algorithm, from the same places, yes. But that link implements the "vanilla" algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on, the following is a comment snippet from Wordpress 3.1's "\wp-includes\pluggable.php":

```
 /**
 * For integration with other applications, this function can be overwritten to
 * instead use the other package password checking algorithm.
 */
```