# How to convert text password to hashed password in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have tried to convert a text password to hashed password by wp_hash_password() function.But the result password is not same as the password saved in wp_users table

$password = wp_hash_password($password);
I have also tried it by md5($password);
But generated password the not same as the password saved in wp_users table

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does wordpress password hash work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076507/how-does-wordpress-password-hash-work)

Answer (score 1):

The resuling hash is not supposed to be the same. Thats how the hashing was designed, Each stored password has a salt built in.

Wordpress uses Openwalls phpass (http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

This makes it much more secure if there is a leak of the database as each row has its own salt so attacks are on a per password basis rather than a per database basis increasing the time taken for brute force and dictionary attacks etc.

Wordpress provide a function [wp_check_password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password) for checking a password agaist a hash.